# Should I consider microservice as an epic or a project in TFS?

Tags: agile, team-foundation-server, microservices, jira, project-planning

When using tools such as TFS or JIRA to plan an application made of 10+ microservices, I am concerned should I consider microservice as an epic or as an new project?

In TFS when splitting microservices as different projects, the benefit is a separated git repository, but on the other hand it is difficult to plan a single sprint having tasks, stories and bugs from different projects

Comment: Like I commented below, you can have multiple Git repos per project, so you don't really have a problem.

Comment: I'd try to keep all tightly coupled applications with shared developers in a single repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have resources that depend on each other, with resources being [people | work items | code], then they would all be in the same Team Project.

You can easily have separate Teams (Backlogs, Work, & People), Git Repositories (code) all within a single Team Project. If you are using TFVC then use folders.

Check out https://nkdagility.com/creating-nested-teams-visual-studio-alm/ for organising Teams and https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/ for the rational and background.